# CSS | "page-break" is not working

Tags: html, css

So i am actually working on a website and i try to do a button to print the page. I'm working with the **Framework Laravel**.

**view.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('css/printSheet.css') }}" media="print">

...

<div class="container">
   ...
    /* Here i have some dynamic text. */ 
   ...
</div>
```

**printSheet.css** : Here i hidden some part of the web site that don't need to be printed.

```
button#printA {
display: none;
}

... 

nav#navBar {
display: none;
}
```

My issue here is that when do a print, I've got only one page and my text is cut in the middle. I've also try to do "page-break-after: always;" and "page-break-before: always;" but doesn't work to.

If someone can help me **thanks**.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML/CSS you are using? Or even better a working example. It might give an indication on what is going wrong.

Comment: Is this actually Laravel related or CSS related?

Comment: It's actually CSS related.

Comment: Maybe good to mention, there are two ways of applying specific print styles.
1. By wrapping the css in @media print {...} in the css file
2. By adding media="print" to the link tag of the css file
I don't see either of those in your question.

Comment: I'm actually using the second solution by adding the media="print" to the link.